# Import Products magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, product, import

We have to import the products in from magento1.8 to magento1.9,
but we are facing the issue while importing products like
Error: `Image does not exist.`

screenshot:

[image]

we have image path in csv file like:

> /t/_/t_negro_earl_grey_infusiones_chas_tetique_tienda_te_online.jpeg

So, Please help me how to resolve this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Error message simply states that the image path is wrong. Please upload all images under **`/media/import`** folder under document root of Magento in the same folder structure as you mentioned in .csv file.

Then check the .csv file that you don't have any spaces or special characters in the path of images in the .csv file.

Now please import the .csv file by **System > Import (dataflow profiles)**.

**Note:** If you are in doubt that path of images will match with path of images in the folder, then put all images directly in **/media/import** folder and set the path to all images in the .csv file as **/imagename.extension**

For example, if image path is **/t/_/t_negro_earl_grey_infusiones_chas_tetique_tienda_te_online.jpeg**, then change it to **/t_negro_earl_grey_infusiones_chas_tetique_tienda_te_online.jpeg** in the .csv file.

**Update:** If it is more important for you to import products (even without images), then you can remove images columns from CSV file and import products without images first.

Then create a new CSV file with only SKU, image, small_image and thumbnail fields (if you want, you can also add columns for labels of images) and import this CSV with the same process. It will update images in the products by matching products' SKUs.

Please let me know if you find any issue again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, For how many products we should do this, we have lots of products to import.

Comment: Can you please help me if any alternative way

Comment: Please see my updated answer.

Comment: We have tried just import only 3 products, products are imported but not showing up: screenshot: https://prnt.sc/gegoan

Comment: have you done reindexing?

Comment: Yes I have done reindex and removed the cache session.